# REDIRECCION POR INACTIVIDAD

Tags: javascript, html, html5, redirección, redireccionamiento

Necesito crear un codigo en javascript para que me redireccione automaticamente al pasar un tiempo programado de inactividad, quiero que me redirrecione si cumple un cierto tiempo de inactividad (osea sin ningun click o movimiento), me gustaria que concentrara en mi iframe. Aqui les dejo un ejemplo de como es realemnte mi proyecto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
  </head>
      
  <body>
       
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"/>
  <label id="trigger" for="menu-toggle"></label>
  <label id="burger" for="menu-toggle"></label>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.app">INICIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="go:sp.app">SOPORTE</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://action_share">COMPARTIR</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://action_profile">MY CUENTA</a></li>
  </ul><br><br><br><br><br>
//me gustaria que se concentrara en este iframe:
<iframe src="google.com" name="IFRAME" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="1900px" style="border: solid #202124;"></iframe>

  </body>

</html>
```

He intendado muchas cosas pero no me ha funcionado, si me ayudaran se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: te refieres a tiempo de inactividad en toda la pagina? y que si pasa ese tiempo tu iframe te envie a otra pagina?

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ Mm se diria que si, pero lo intente recientemente y me funciona, pero al pasar un tiempo no me toma en cuenta el iframe (osea que si utilizo otra secciones que no sea el iframe me calcula la activdad pero si utilizo el iframe no me calcula la actividad), y eso es lo que no me gusta, estaria muy agradecido si alguien sabe como hacerlo.

Comment: agrega el codigo de Javascript de lo que intentaste

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ Este es el codigo:     <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pepe;
function ini() {
  pepe = setTimeout('location="/home"',10000); // 5 segundos
}
function parar() {
  clearTimeout(pepe);
  pepe = setTimeout('location="/home"',10000); // 5 segundos
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="ini()" onkeypress="parar()" onclick="parar()">

  
 <embed src="goggle.coom"
               width="100%" 
               height="1100px" />
</body>
</html>

Comment: edita la pregunta, no agregues el código por comentarios :) de paso, al editarla, tu pregunta volverá a tener visibilidad

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ parce muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero me temo decirte que de la manera que usted coloco anteriormente es erronea, ose funciona en toda la pagina pero en los embed/iframe no funcionan, creo que es porque no me mide el tiempo de visita dentro del embed/iframe. Si tienes una nueva idea me encataria que me ka dijieras. Feliz tarde y gracias.

Comment: hablame por [aca](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146318/conversacion)